# How to locate file faster with over 70000+ files in android

Tags: android, file, system

We are working on app for android. Will have over 65,000 file(small file) on disk. And our app will be doing lots of action:  locate file given absolute path.

So we are thinking, how to organize files to optimize performance of locating file given absolute path.

With very limited knowledge on android, here are some questions we have:

1. What is max file one android folder can hold?
2. is it worth effort to subdirectory those files to optimize performance?

Thanks

Comment: Now that you have so many files please do some test spreading them over for instance 70 and 700 directories. Then tell us. Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about using something like a database (something like SQLite) instead?

Comment: We will store path in sql light, but file itself need to be on disk.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maximum files limit is a file system feature, not an OS feature, at first you should know which file system it uses, two file systems are used at most, ext4 and f2fs
2. After knowing which file system it uses, you can search for documentation about that file system, for example how many files can hold a single directory, or which length can have a file path and so on. But as I guess, it will be performance issues with large amount of files, for example when you call File.listFiles() method, so it will be better to use small number of files in a single directory.

### UPDATED

1. Created one small text file with 10 characters, and then read file content, it took 5 milliseconds to complete
2. At first tried to create 50000 files, first thousand files created fast, but when it reach to 20000, creating performance dramatically reduced and I stopped process
3. Read 10000th created file, it also took 5 milliseconds to complete, it seems that retrieving a file is fast, but writing is long, when there are a lot of files, besides that clear app data in the application manager took very long, so it will be better to not store large amount files in single directory because writing is slow

Used Sony Xperia Z2 tablet with 4GB free space. Here are source code and logcat output

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long s1 = s;
            for(int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
                createFile(i);
                if(i % 1000 == 0) {
                    Log.v("#TEST#", String.format("i = %d", i));
                    Log.v("#TEST# createFile", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - s1));
                    s1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
            long e = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.v("#TEST# createAllFiles", Long.toString(e - s));

            readFile(25000);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }.execute();
}

private void createFile(int index) {
    File dir = getExternalFilesDir("txt");
    String filename = String.format("file_%d.txt", index);
    File file = new File(dir, filename);
    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(stream);
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(filename);
        dataOutputStream.close();
        stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readFile(int index) {
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    File dir = getExternalFilesDir("txt");
    File file = new File(dir, String.format("file_%d.txt", index));
    try {
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(stream);
        String text = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        dataInputStream.close();
        stream.close();
        long e = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.v("#TEST# readFile", Long.toString(e - s));
        Log.v("#TEST# readFile", text);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
    02-21 14:09:00.119  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 0
    02-21 14:09:00.119  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 18
    02-21 14:09:09.639  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 1000
    02-21 14:09:09.639  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 9519
    02-21 14:09:23.039  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 2000
    02-21 14:09:23.039  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 13397
    02-21 14:09:38.929  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 3000
    02-21 14:09:38.929  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 15894
    02-21 14:09:55.379  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 4000
    02-21 14:09:55.379  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 16444
    02-21 14:10:12.089  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 5000
    02-21 14:10:12.089  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 16707
    02-21 14:10:30.209  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 6000
    02-21 14:10:30.209  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 18122
    02-21 14:10:49.069  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 7000
    02-21 14:10:49.069  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 18860
    02-21 14:11:08.799  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 8000
    02-21 14:11:08.799  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 19732
    02-21 14:11:29.489  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 9000
    02-21 14:11:29.489  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 20686
    02-21 14:11:51.899  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 10000
    02-21 14:11:51.899  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 22410
    02-21 14:12:13.659  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 11000
    02-21 14:12:13.659  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 21762
    02-21 14:12:37.419  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 12000
    02-21 14:12:37.419  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 23761
    02-21 14:13:04.109  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 13000
    02-21 14:13:04.109  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 26689
    02-21 14:13:32.729  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 14000
    02-21 14:13:32.729  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 28616
    02-21 14:14:03.219  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 15000
    02-21 14:14:03.219  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 30494
    02-21 14:14:34.319  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 16000
    02-21 14:14:34.319  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 31105
    02-21 14:15:07.339  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 17000
    02-21 14:15:07.339  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 33015
    02-21 14:15:42.509  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 18000
    02-21 14:15:42.509  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 35169
    02-21 14:16:19.029  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 19000
    02-21 14:16:19.029  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 36521
    02-21 14:16:55.839  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST#﹕ i = 20000
    02-21 14:16:55.839  12601-12619/com.example.messie.androidtest V/#TEST# createFile﹕ 36811
```

Comment: i am mostly interested in android. I guess it is mostly yaffs2 system.

Comment: I guess i don't really care about list files (ls or dir) performance, since i know absolute path of file.

Comment: In that case don't worry about performance, I don't know yaffs2, but in all oher file systems, paths are indexed, and yaffs2 will be no exception

Comment: Understood, path will be indexed. However, give number of files (65k plus), and it will be random access, not sure directory cache will hold that many entries.  Hence, I thought we would still assume every access, OS still need to find directory, and look for physical location of file within it.

Comment: We can know an exact answer to check source codes, and do some tests, interesting question, worth experiments in this weekend :)

Comment: Updated an answer, can check it :)